# var_dump output using foreach reference loop

Tags: php, foreach, var-dump

I am using a foreach loop with referencing, ie: `foreach($elements as &$item)`

Now when I use `var_dump($elements);` after the `foreach()`, the last element always has an `&` character prepended to it's variable-type (`&string`, `&array`, `&boolean`, etc).

Example output:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "this"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "is"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "an"
  [3]=>
  &string(7) "example"
}
```

Why is this and what functionality / impact does it have?

Comment: It is the address pointer. You can `unset($item)` to avoid this

Comment: What did you do in the foreach loop???

Comment: @thamilian ah okay, I didn't realize that, could you add that as the answer?

Comment: @frayne it can be empty and it will still happen

Comment: I must with go @Thamilan, This is a pointer and it points the last element of the array as you use foreach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the address pointer. You can `unset($item)` to avoid this.

Answers for your question:

***1. Why is this*** :

You can find the reference in the [manual](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

> **Warning** Reference of a $value and the last array element remain even
>   after the foreach loop. It is recommended to destroy it by unset().

This arises when you use reference in your foreach loop. The reference resides with the last array element.

***2. What functionality / impact does it have***

Consider this situation:

```
<?php
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
foreach ($arr as &$value) {
}

print_r($arr);

foreach ($arr as $value) {
}

print_r($arr);
```

Your output will be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 3  <---
)
```

If you use `unset`:

```
<?php
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
foreach ($arr as &$value) {
}

print_r($arr);
unset($value);  <---

foreach ($arr as $value) {
}

print_r($arr);
```

Result will be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4  <---
)
```